# Unzipping file in PHP extracts no files

Tags: php, apache

I've installed Apache on Ubuntu 16.04 server:

```
sudo apt-get install apache2 libapache2-mod-fastcgi libapache2-mod-php7.0 php7.0 php7.0-mcrypt php7.0-zip proftpd-basic
```

but when I run a PHP script to unzip an archive on the server, 
the script says Ok but no file is extracted from the file.zip archive.

```
set_time_limit(0);

$zip = new ZipArchive;
if ($zip->open('file.zip') === TRUE) {
    $zip->extractTo('.');
    $zip->close();
    echo 'ok';
} else {
    echo 'failure';
}
```

Comment: $zip->extractTo('.');
i think you mean     $zip->extractTo('/'); ?

Comment: No, a dot means the current directory. 
But anyway, this script works fine as I've used it for years.

Comment: After running few tests it turns out that it comes from a permission problem 
`FastCGI: server "/usr/lib/cgi-bin/php-fcgi" stderr: PHP message: PHP Warning:  ZipArchive::extractTo(): Permission denied in /var/www/web/html/unzip.php on line 6`
But I can't really figure out why this pb occurs.
Both files (unzip.hp and file.zip) are chmod 644 and chown is set to the proper user (not to www-data).

Any idea ?